# netlogo programing help on sheep-wolves simulation

Tags: netlogo

Netlogo programming questions.

Sheep are fixed with 10000 energy and wolves move around with 100 energy.
When wolves run out of energy, they eat sheep, replenish energy, and reduce sheep's energy, but coding is difficult. Look at the coding, please.

What about wolf energy increase and positive energy reduction coding?

-----------start-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
breed [wolves wolf]                

breed [sheep a-sheep]              

wolves-own [
  energy
]               

sheep-own [
  energy
]              

to setup
  clear-all     
  set-default-shape sheep "house"   


  create-sheep number-of-sheep[     
    setxy -17 -25                   
    set color green                 
    set size 3                     
    set energy 10000                 
  ]

    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy 9 -26                     
    set color green                 
    set size 3                     
    set energy 10000
  ]



   create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy 25 -21                     
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000
  ]



    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy 4 28                      
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000
  ]


    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy -13 27                    
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000

  ]


    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy 17 -7                     
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000

  ]


    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy -13 33                     
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000

  ]

    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy 15 12                      
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000

  ]


    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy -3 11                      
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000

  ]


    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy 23 38                     
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000

  ]


    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy 4 21                     
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000

  ]


    create-sheep number-of-sheep [
    setxy -24 16                   
    set color green
    set size 3
    set energy 10000

  ]

  create-wolves number-of-wolves [   
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor      
    set color blue                    
    set size 2.5
    set shape "airplane"               
    set energy 100                     
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if not any? wolves [stop]
  ask wolves [
    wiggle
    move
    check-if-dead
    eat
  ]
  tick
  my-update-plots
end

to eat
  if breed = sheep
  [eat-sheep]
 
end

to eat-sheep
  if any? sheep-here [
    let target one-of sheep-here
    ask target [
      die
    ]
    set energy energy + energy-gain-from-sheep
  ]
end



to check-if-dead
  if energy < 1 [
  die
]
end

to wiggle
  right random 90
  left random 90
 end

to move
  forward 1
  set energy energy - 1
end

to my-update-plots
  set-current-plot-pen "sheep"
  plot count sheep
  set-current-plot-pen "wolves"
  plot count wolves
end
```

---------------------end-------------------------------------------------

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I formatted your code so the question is readable. However, I can't actually see a question here. What is it that you are trying to do and where does it fail? Are you getting an error message or is the behaviour wrong? It would help if you only provided the code relevant to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I want to reduce the energy of sheep after wolves use energy of sheep.  Can you see my question and coding uploading here?

Comment: I can see text. But StackOverflow is about helping you to fix your code. You need to identify the section of code that is attempting to do whatever you are trying to do, and tell us what's wrong with it (like an error message, or it does the wrong thing).

Comment: I think there's a logical error in your code:
You ask the wolves to eat ( in the `go` procedure), but in the `eat` procedure, you check, it the breed is sheep. That can't ever be the case. I think you can replace the `eat` in the `go` procedure by `eat-sheep`.
If  `energy-gain-from-sheep` is set in the interface, it should work